# How to insert json field values Postgresql 14

Tags: json, postgresql

I am trying to insert some data into my Postgres table. There is a column which includes some json Data. But every time I try to insert it shows some error

Below is my query

```
INSERT INTO settings.tbl_settings 
    (sin_product_id, 
    vhr_sys_module_name, 
    vhr_grouping_name,
    vhr_settings_sys_name, 
    vhr_label,
    vhr_value, 
    arj_select_items,
    txt_remarks,
    vhr_widget_type,
    sin_settings_category, 
    int_sys_action_id, 
    fk_created_user_id, 
    dtm_created)
VALUES
    (1, 
    'XO_PURCHASE', 
    'XO Purchase',
    'NEED_XO_PURCHASE_SUPPLIER_SIDE_POSTING', 
    'Need XO Purchase Supplier Side Posting', 
    'NO_POSTING', 
    '[{"strSysName":"NO_POSTING","strLabel":"No Posting"} ,{"strSysName":"POSTING","strLabel":"Posting"}]'::JSONB[],
    '',
    'SELECTBOX',
    2, 
    0, 
    1, 
    TO_TIMESTAMP('27-08-2022 17.24.34', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    );
```

It Returns Given Error

```
ERROR:  malformed array literal: "[{"strSysName":"NO_POSTING","strLabel":"No Posting"} ,{"strSysName":"POSTING","strLabel":"Posting"}]"
LINE 27:                             '[{"strSysName":"NO_POSTING","st...
                                     ^
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 1024
```

Comment: Sounds as if `arj_select_items` is defined as an array, not a `jsonb` (or at least `json`) column

Comment: You have a `jsonb` literal, not a `jsonb[]` literal.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you Can you please more Specific? @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that when you perform the insert operation, you convert the string into a jsonb array (`::JSONB[]`), but you just need to jsonb, since the type of your `arj_select_items` column is most likely defined as jsonb.

Demo in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=df822987d115ae129682779f9d4d5534)